# Excel use a function based on user language

Tags: excel, excel-formula, localization

I'm trying to generate a report in Excel but the thing is that my user base are English and French Canadian...

Because of the law in Quebec, the sofware is supposed to be french, but the other user in Canada  can have it in English.

- Issue is, I don't know which language settings will have the user enabled
- I wanted to use some of [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) formula like `CONCATENATE`, but in the french version the function name is translated to `CONCATENER`

Thus, I can't use the formula, I would need to know the user lang settings in excel and find a way to use the appropriate function accordingly...

Does anybody know a way to bypass the function name regardless of the user language ?

I got another way of outputing the correct information without using the formula, but it would required more effort for the little return it would give...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use an **inbuilt** excel function in your local language settings, it will automatically be converted to their language setting if the user opens it with their own excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

- Don't worry about it, it will work. Just use the functions as normal

---

**Long**er **answer:**

If you use an **inbuilt** [excel](/questions/tagged/excel) function *(which `CONCATENATE` is)*, it will automatically be converted to the user's installed and enabled language settings.

---

> As an example, if I open this workbook with English settings enabled:
>
> [image]
>
> ---
>
> The function is the English standard `=ISNUMBER`
>
> Meanwhile, if I were to open this, with Czech language on:
>
> [image]
>
> *Also note, how not only the function name changed, but also the Cell value to local settings*

Alternatively, if you wanted to play it ultra-safe, you could code your own versions of the functions in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) creating both English and French versions - but in my humble opinion, that's a total waste of time!

---

Also obviously this being only specific to `CONCATENATE`, you can use the ampersand <kbd>&</kbd> symbol instead to concatenate two values instead, which is global and will stay the same in any language settings.

```
= "Cell A2 has value " & A2
```

Comment: I tested the function CONCATENATE, and it doesn't work with the French version in office 365 PRO, it give me a "Erreur du a un nom non valide" which is probably because of the data I'm using, but it is working with the French version CONCATENER so I'm not really sure about it... the ampersand & does work though

Comment: I think that's because `CONCATENATE` was only added in the more recent versions, but I might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

Is `CONCATENATE()` the only function? Because in that case, you might use the `&` operator:

```
=A1&B1
```

Comment: For now I'm using only CONCATENATE, so I will use the & thanks for the reply